# Changing value of a variable based on condition in R

Tags: r, recode

I am trying to change a value for a variable depending on other variables. So if value of one variable equals that of second variable then value of third variable should be multiplied by -1.

My code looks like this:

```
df <- df %>%
       mutate (C = case_when((A1) == (A2) & (R1) == (R2) ~ C,
                                (A1) == (R1) & (A2) == (R2) ~ (-1L)*C))
```

where A1, A2, R1, R2 are character variables and C is a numerical variable.

I get

```
error: case_when(...)`.
must be a double vector, not a logical vector.
```

If I change (-1L) to (-1) then it gives me NA for C

TIA!!

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. To help you, plese follow these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following will solve the problem.
Instead of checking the condition where there are no changes, leave only the changes condition and all others in the `TRUE` clause.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    C = case_when(
      (A1 == R1) & (A2 == R2) ~ -1L*C,
      TRUE ~ C
  ))
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestion yet the error remains same.

Comment: Hello  - sorry it worked when I redid my whole script. Not sure what went wrong at the initial time. Thanks!!